# функция проверяющая слово Изограмма или нет, код длинный, можете помочь укоротить

Tags: javascript

```js
function solution(x){
 if (x.split(" ").length > 1) {
  return false
 }
 let k = x.toLowerCase()
 k = k.split("")
 if (k.length == 0) {
  return false
 }
 if (k == "") {
  return false
 }
 for (let i = 0; i < k.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < k.length; j++) {
   if (!isNaN(parseInt(k[i],10))) {
    return false
   }
   if (k[i] == k[j] && i != j) {
    return false
   }
  }
 }
 return true
}
console.log(solution("izogramma"));
console.log(solution("izogram"));
```

Comment: Что не работает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё вроде работает, всего вроде хватает, разве что покороче можно.

```js
function solution(x) {
  const k = x.toLowerCase().split("");
  if (k.length == 0) {
    return false;
  }
  return k.every((l, i) => !k.find((k,j) => i != j && l == k));
}
console.log(solution("izogramma"));
console.log(solution("izogram"));
```